# Executing bat file within Java program

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

How do I execute a .bat or .exe within my java program that is in a sub-folder within the main folder that holds my java program.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start example.bat");
```

The code above works perfectly fine when the .bat is in the same folder as the java program. But if my program's .java and .class files were organized in a package (and the .bat would be in a separate folder), how would I call that bat program?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If the .bat file is in a different folder you should pass its full absolute path to cmd.exe. Also, to get the correct quoting you should use the method that takes an array as argument:

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd", "/c", "start", path};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

If you know the location of the .bat file relative to your .jar file, you can find it using the properties of the Class object. See for example [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

May not be feasible in your case, but what if you added the location of the batch file to your execution path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full absolute path to example.bat or the relative path from your Working directory.